# Remove Ubuntu and install Ubuntu Server as a fresh start

Tags: installation, server, uninstall

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed on my laptop and I want to remove it and install Ubuntu Server. How would I do that?

Comment: [Download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server), burn the CD/DVD, put it on your drive, restart, in your boot screen select CD/DVD from the boot list, follow the installation steps, finish.

Answer (score 1):

Download the server install CD from here [Ubuntu 12.04 - Server Install CD](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/) burn it to a CD , boot from CD and re-install.

See here a tutorial about sever installation : [Ubuntugeek.com](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/step-by-step-ubuntu-12-04-precise-lamp-server-setup.html) and better would be to install first in VirtualBox to see how the installation progress is and then make it for real.

About VirtualBox see here: [Ubuntu community wiki- Virtualbox](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox)

Comment: thats what i did and when i installed i got an error during bootloader installation and it put me back to the installation screen . i skipped the step and when it reboots i just get a blinking _ and nothing happens

Comment: Try to use this automatic tool from a liveCD (not server CD) : [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_:_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu)

Comment: @Dany  It may have been faulty media.  You might try burning again.